# Enable Reasoning for SPARQL request via Jena?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, virtuoso, reasoning

### Problem environment:

I have to access some RDF data stored in a virtuoso server via SPARQL. Reasoning has to be enabled for that graph I want to access. On the client side jena 2.11.x has to be used.

### Now the problem:

To enable reasoning I have to add the line `define input:inference „http://examplegraphIRI“` as first line of the SPARQL query according to http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html. If I use Jena `QueryExecutionFactory` to execute the Query, it will be rejected since ARQ cannot parse the given line.

### Now the questions:

Am I required to use the Virtuoso Jena Provider (http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider#Bypass%20Jena/ARQ%20parser)? Will it work for my problem (the latest version (http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider) states it is intended for jena 2.10.x)?

Are there other possibilities to enable reasoning for a SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: Question also asked on [OpenLink's support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=6342).

Comment: @Tallted Yes, I also posted it in the support forum but the answer there took longer than my own research and the answer there is more like a workaround since it requires using vendor specific libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by browsing through the source-code of Jena and ARQ:

instead of using the `final QueryEngineHTTP request = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(String,Query)` I could bypass the parser by using `final QueryEngineHTTP request = new QueryEngineHTTP (this.endpoint, fullQueryString)` directly.